# Azure Detect With Stream Invalid Request

Tags: python, azure

it's my first time with Azure Face Detection API and I'm using this code right here:

```
import os
import io
import cv2
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

API_KEY = '...'
ENDPOINT = '...'
image = open('realmadrid.jpg', 'rb')

face_client = FaceClient(ENDPOINT, CognitiveServicesCredentials(API_KEY))


response_detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(
    image=image,
    detection_model='detection_03',
    recognition_model='recognition_04',
    return_face_landmarks=True,
)

if not response_detected_faces:
    raise Exception("No face detected!")

print(f"Number of face detected {len(response_detected_faces)}")
```

The problem is that everytime I run this code it gives me an exception:

```
/home/thecowmilk/dev/azure_faceapi/venv/bin/python /home/thecowmilk/dev/azure_faceapi/faceapi/starting.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thecowmilk/dev/azure_faceapi/faceapi/starting.py", line 20, in <module>
    detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(
  File "/home/thecowmilk/dev/azure_faceapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/face/operations/_face_operations.py", line 782, in detect_with_stream
    raise models.APIErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models._models_py3.APIErrorException: (InvalidRequest) Invalid request has been sent.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know how to solve this. It looks there's not much info about Azure Face Detection API. I'd appreciate your thoughts <3!

Answer (score 0):

- According to [Get face landmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/how-to/identity-detect-faces#get-face-landmarks), to get face landmark data, set the detectionModel parameter to `DetectionModel.Detection01` and the `returnFaceLandmarks` parameter to `true`.

```
IList<DetectedFace> faces2 = await faceClient.Face.DetectWithUrlAsync(url: imageUrl, returnFaceId: true, returnFaceLandmarks: true, detectionModel: DetectionModel.Detection01);
```

Instead of `detection_03` use `detection_01`:

```
response_detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(
    image=image,
    detection_model='detection_01',
    recognition_model='recognition_04',
    return_face_landmarks=True,
)
```

You can refer to recent changes/limitations about some features of Face API: [Responsible AI investments and safeguards for facial recognition](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/responsible-ai-investments-and-safeguards-for-facial-recognition/)